# iOS Objective-Cにおいて，UITextViewに入力しているテキストの変換作業をキャンセルさせたい。

Tags: ios, objective-c

添付画像AからBの状態へ，プログラム制御でもっていくにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。
言い換えると，UITextViewにおいて(画像ではHTMLのフォームですが…)，markedTextRange内にある未確定な入力中の文字列を消し，且つ，キーボードの予測変換もクリアしたいのですが，なかなか情報が見つかりませんでした。
TextViewへのフォーカスは外れず，カーソル位置もそのままで入力を続けることができると有難いです。

画像には載せていませんが，自身で実装したサジェストリストが画面に表示され，そのセルがタップされたとき，本来のOS付属のキーボードの変換候補一覧はすでに不要なのでクリアしたいのです。
わかりづらい説明で申し訳有りませんが，APIなどをご存知の方は教えていただけると助かります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

まず、File's ownerの @interface 部に

```
@interface クラス名 <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOUtlet UITextField *wantsToCancelable;
}
```

等として、編集をキャンセルしたいテキストフィールドのアウトレットを作成し、アウトレットを接続して内容にアクセス出来るようにします。
後は、@implementationに、

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
```

内で

```
[wantsToCancelable setDelegate:self];
```

とするか、UITextFileldのDelegateプロパティ（左クリックで出てくる黒い窓）のDelegateをFile's Ownerにします。

最後に

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

を実装して、その内部で編集中の文字列をチェックすれば良いと思います。
内容の取り出しと設定（キャンセル）は

```
[wantsToCancelable stringValue];
[wantsToCancelable setStringValue:newString];
```

で、行います。空白に戻すにはnewStringに@""を渡して下さい。